# s3 presigned url mandatory custom request headers

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, custom-headers

I am trying to generate a presigned url with some user data along with,
as I understand I need to use custom request headers

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucket, objectKey)
        .withMethod(httpMethod)
        .withExpiration(expiration);
if (params != null) {
  params.forEach(
      (k, v) ->
          generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader(
              Headers.S3_USER_METADATA_PREFIX + k.toLowerCase(), v));
}
return s3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Even though the consumer of generated url needs to set the headers.
Is there any way we can enforce the consumer to add these headers ?
eg : throw Bad Request (400) when required header (custom) is not present

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [addRequestParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#addRequestParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)? This will add query string parameters and without those params request will be failed.

E.g.

```
generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter(Headers.S3_USER_METADATA_PREFIX + "test", "true");
```

Generated url will contain following param:

```
https://aws-domain/file.ext?x-amz-meta-test=true&X-Amz-Security-Token=<TOKEN>
```

### Update:

I've been using [getSignedUrl API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) in Node.js to generate signed url with user metadata in query string parameters. I am not a JAVA developer which is why I suggested you to use `addRequestParameter` which appears to generate signed url with meta data supplied in the method.

**Node.js code**

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
  'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
  'Key': 'signed.json',
  'Metadata': {
    'my-id': '1234'
  }
});
```

**Signed URL**:

```
https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/signed.json?AWSAccessKeyId=<AccessKey>&Expires=1549497606&Signature=<SignatureKey>&x-amz-meta-my-id=1234
```

**Upload file**:

```
curl -k -X PUT -T "signed.json" "https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/signed.json?AWSAccessKeyId=<AccessKey>&Expires=1549497606&Signature=<SignatureKey>&x-amz-meta-my-id=1234"
```

**User metadata**:

[image]

Client won't need to add any headers in order to be able to add user metadata. If client attempts to modify x-amz-meta-* or remove it they will get `SignatureDoesNotMatch` which is exactly what you want.

**Modify x-amz-meta-my-id**

```
curl -k -X PUT -T "signed.json" "https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/signed.json?AWSAccessKeyId=<AccessKey>&Expires=1549497606&Signature=<SignatureKey>&x-amz-meta-my-id=123"
```

Expected error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ5PO6T7F772ZPSPQ</AWSAccessKeyId>
```

Comment: url will contain these metadata, but how can I access this data in the other side ?
S3Object user data is not populated with this RequestParameters, only with headers right ?

Comment: You don't need to access that data you've already specified that you need that metadata when URL is used. So if client attempts to remove one of the added params the request will be failed. Yes it will add the metadata.

Comment: x-amz-meta-test=true
how can I access this data at later point of time ?
basically I am adding additional information, if it dosent get stored then no use right ?
ref https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=297677

Comment: did you check if meta data is actually being added in the object?

Comment: how can I check meta data from query params is actually being added in the object ?

Comment: @A.Khan I was not aware that `x-amz-meta-*` was actually processed from the query string by the `PUT` object API.  That isn't documented behavior -- these are supposed to be request headers, not query string parameters.  I'm curious to see whether that actually has the intended effect or whether it simply becomes a tamper-resistant no-op.

Comment: Note also that if OP just adds these *as headers* when generating the pre-signed URL, S3 will reject the upload with `SignatureDoesNotMatch` if the client fails to add them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I know it works because I'm currently using it using AWS JS SDK in one of my projects. As you said, this is not a documented behaviour at least I couldn't find it. Because I am not a JAVA developer which is why I asked OP to test with `addRequestParameter` it appears to add query string params and generate the same URL as I would expect from js sdk. I am going to update my answer to put my Node.js code.